# Is zero condition mean preserved after transforming the conditioned variable?

Tags: regression, probability, econometrics, gauss-markov-theorem

In my econometrics class regarding multiple linear regression, we learned that one of the Gauss-Markov assumptions is the zero conditional mean, expressed as $ E(y|\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$.

My question is: If we transform  $\boldsymbol{x}$ into $g(\boldsymbol{x})$, does this zero conditional mean still hold for the new conditioned variable? In other words, does $E(y|g(\boldsymbol{x})) = 0$ for arbitrary $g$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) is useful here.

In particular, the function $g$ can at best maintain your information set, but may decrease it (e.g., when $g$ is such that it drops some regressor from $x$). And given that the smaller information set dominates, we may write
$$
E[y|g(x)]=E[E(y|x)|g(x)],
$$
which, by assumption, equals $E[0|g(x)]=0$.

Comment: You may want to check your notes again in that $y$ is often the notation for the dependent variable in your regression model, where the assumption of a zero conditional mean is typically for the error term, i.e., something like $E(u|x)=0$.

Indeed, *if* we had $E(y|x)=0$ that would be tantamount to saying that there is no (mean) relationship between $y$ and $x$, which would imply that regressing $y$ on $x$ would not be interesting.

Comment: +1. This actually is a special case of $\mathbb E(X\mid \mathfrak G_1\mid \mathfrak G_2) =\mathbb E(X\mid \mathfrak G_2)$ where $\mathfrak G_1, \mathfrak G_2$ are sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathfrak F$ and $\mathfrak G_2\subset \mathfrak G_1.$